# Symfony set base route for all controllers that extend a certain controller

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony4

Let's assume in Symfony you have a `BackendController`.

Then all backend controllers follow e.g. `ProjectsController extends BackendController`.

Is there a way to set Symfony up so that all controllers that extend `BackendController` route to `somesite.com/auth`

Such that

```
class ProjectsController extends BackendController
{

    /**
     * @Route("projects");
     */
    public function index()  {
```

route `projects` resolves to `auth/projects` without having to explicitly state it `@Route("auth/projects");`?

Please be gentle; I'm extremely new to Symfony.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class level route definitions are not inherited meaning that this isn't possible. The next best thing you can do is to define that base route separately on class level for all controllers inheriting the base class:

```
/**                                                                             
 * @Route("/auth")
 */
class ProjectsController extends BackendController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/projects");
     */
    public function index()  {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```